# GetAsyncMethod in Visual Studio says that not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-8

I am looking at the method and cannot see why the code paths don't return a value. I am actually trying to make a blog reader from channel 9. Just a follow along application. While learning to code I'm finding it hard to find projects to do. I just keep watching videos and reading books. Its just easier if there are projects to examine the source code from and figure out how they work. So thats the context of this program. In Visual Studio this is the only error I have in the file it says. That method.GetFeedAsync: not all code paths return a value.. This is exactly how the developer had it in the video but there is no commenting system on the page anymore because of how old it is. The series is listed [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Build-a-Windows-Store-Blog-Reader-app-with-C-)

```
     private async Task<FeedData> GetFeedAsync(string feedUriString)
        {
            SyndicationClient client = new SyndicationClient();
            Uri feedUri = new Uri(feedUriString);
            try
            {
                SyndicationFeed feed = await client.RetrieveFeedAsync(feedUri);
                FeedData feedData = new FeedData();

                if (feed.Title != null && feed.Title.Text != null)
                {
                    feedData.Title = feed.Title.Text;
                }
                if (feed.Subtitle != null && feed.Subtitle.Text != null)
                {
                    feedData.Description = feed.Subtitle.Text;
                }
                if (feed.Items != null && feed.Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    //use the date of the latest post as the last updated date
                    feedData.PubDate = feed.Items[0].PublishedDate.DateTime;
                    foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
                    {
                        FeedItem feedItem = new FeedItem();
                        if (item.Title != null && item.Title.Text != null)
                        {
                            feedItem.Title = item.Title.Text;
                        }
                        if (item.PublishedDate != null)
                        {
                            feedItem.PubDate = item.PublishedDate.DateTime;
                        }
                        if (item.Authors != null && item.Authors.Count > 0)
                        {
                            feedItem.Author = item.Authors[0].Name.ToString();
                        }

                        if (feed.SourceFormat == SyndicationFormat.Atom10)
                        {
                            if (item.Content != null && item.Content.Text != null)
                            {
                                feedItem.Content = item.Content.Text;
                            }
                            if (item.Id != null)
                            {
                                feedItem.Link = new Uri("http://windowsteamblog.com" + item.Id);
                            }
                            else if (feed.SourceFormat == SyndicationFormat.Rss20)
                            {
                                if (item.Summary != null && item.Summary.Text != null)
                                {
                                    feedItem.Content = item.Summary.Text;
                                }

                                if (item.Links != null && item.Links.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    feedItem.Link = item.Links[0].Uri;
                                }
                            }
                            feedData.Items.Add(feedItem);

                        }

                    }
                    return feedData;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                return null;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your return feedData is within an if statement, it is possible for the try block to successfully execute without exception and not encounter a return statement.

You should move the return statement to outside the if statement (ie, swap it with the } below it) or introduce an else statement that returns something, depending on desired behavior.

```
        try
        {
           // lots of code emitted

            if (feed.Items != null && feed.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                // lots more code emitted 
            }

            return feedData;

        }
```

or

```
        try
        {
           // lots of code emitted

            if (feed.Items != null && feed.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                // lots more code emitted 

                return feedData;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }

        }
```

Should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (feed.Items != null && feed.Items.Count > 0)
```

If the above condition is not met, then nothing is returned, hence the error message.

You probably meant to put the `return feedData;` line outside the scope of this `if` block.